# symfony 2 Group Permission Doctrine issue

Tags: php, mysql, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I am using below query in my symfony 2.7 project.

```
$query = "SELECT u.username,u.id FROM user u, user_user_group uug,user_group ug WHERE uug.group_id = ug.id AND ug.name='Account Manager' AND u.id = uug.user_id";

$result = $this->getEntityManager()->getConnection()->executeQuery($query)->fetchAll();
```

Client wants this query in doctrine only not the core query..!!

The main issue is here **user_user_group** table don't have entity so i am not making the join in doctrine query.

if i create the **user_user_group** entity then it will create the issue in force query syntax of symfony which is required in my project.

If you have any idea then please let me know. i am stuck with that.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Is it so that you have a `User`-entity and a `Group`-entity mapped as a `ManyToMany` relation?

Comment: user and user_group are 2 different entities and they don't have any relationships. in user_user_group table 2 fields are there that is user_id and group_id(user_group > id)

Comment: Why don't they have a mapped relation? With it, you could use the query-builder.

Comment: How ? can you gives me a example

Comment: It's a bit weird, it seems you use doctrine, yet not in the way it is meant to be. Have you read the [docs](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/association-mapping.html)?

Answer (score 0):

You can use, nativequery with Doctrine Entities
[Native Query Documentation](http://docs.doctrine-project.org/projects/doctrine-orm/en/latest/reference/native-sql.html#the-nativequery-class)